# Writing SQL in Informatica Data Quality Analyst

Tags: sql, informatica

I am new to Informatica Data Quality Analyst (Version 9.5.1 HotFix3) and I am having trouble in generating a basic SQL statement.

The SQL statement is being written against a mapping specification of a table that was originally imported as a flat file. The statement looks like:

```
Select ColumnA, ColumnB FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.ColumnA = 'S'
```

The SELECT .... FROM portion of the statement works fine but I encounter errors when I throw in the WHERE clause. I think my statement looks like standard SQL so I'm not sure why this will not work. Does Informatica Analyst accept SQL written only in a specific form? Are the inverted commas causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

the query must work which you are trying to execute. If its not fetching the results, you need to do the following steps:

1) Load the data from source flat file to any database(oracle). You can directly import the data from flat file to table via sql developer.

2) Execute the query with the filter condition. If it doesnt fetch any rows, your query in idq is fetching correct results. If not, there is something missing in your idq code.